# What could be the cause of 'app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...' error when running NodeJS app on port 5000?

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodeJS and I have just started setting everything up for an app that I am trying to build. I set up two typescript files and put them under the source, they are called app.ts and server.ts however when I go to run the file on the port 5000, it says [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

App.ts:

```
import express, { Application, Router, Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
const app: Application = express();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    res.status(200).json({ success: 'Hello Server'});
});

module.exports = app;
```

Server.ts

```
import http from 'http';
const app = require('./app');

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on port ${port}`));
```

so I figured out that port 5000 specifically wasn't available beacuse when I ran it on 4999 it worked. I do not know why 5000 is taken though I have killed all ports already. I am on an m1 mac. Is 5000 used by default or something?

Comment: Seems like your port 5000 is already in use? Be sure no other app is running that uses port 5000 then run it again.

Comment: it turns out that apparently by default macOS uses port 5000. If anyone else encounters this, go to settings, and turn off airplay receiving.

Comment: As far as I know, port 5000 is generally reserved to Universal Plug and Play, aka `UPnP`